# Users cannot access Shared documents in TFS projects

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have created several projects in TFS 2010 for which SharePoint sites are also created.

Users that have access to projects (are members of predefined Contributors security group on project level) complain that they cannot access Shared documents through Visual Studio. All users are domain members.

Is there anything else related to users permissions that needs to be done in order they to be able to open Shared documents from VS? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to grant needed permissions on specific SharePoint sites related to projects too.

I recommend you to create AD security groups for each project, and grant permissions for every group respectively. That should solve your issues – users will then be able to access Shared documents in TFS projects.